# How to get current location from GPRS on Android without GPS and internet connection?

Tags: android, gps, location, gprs

We could get the current location from GPS on background service. But We want to get the current location when user turned gps off, and does not have Internet Connection!

We found that in XiaoMi phones, below code is working fine. But in other Phones like samsung, lg, we could not get the desired result.

So how can we get the current location without internet and gps in Samsung, LG other phones except Xiaomi?

```
package uz.codic.ahmadtea.ui.dashboard.maps;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.util.Log;

    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

    public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {
        boolean isGPSEnable = false;
        boolean isNetworkEnable = false;
        double latitude, longitude;
        LocationManager locationManager;
        Location location;
        private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        private Timer mTimer = new Timer();
        long notify_interval = 1000;
        public static String str_receiver = "servicetutorial.service.receiver";
        Intent intent;
        private static final String TAG="MYLLOCC";

        public LocationService() {

        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            mTimer = new Timer();
            mTimer.schedule(new TimerTaskToGetLocation(), 5, notify_interval);
            intent = new Intent(str_receiver);
    //        fn_getlocation();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.d(TAG,"MMMMMMMMMM: "+location.getLatitude());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Status changed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Provide enabled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Provide dissabled");
        }

        private void fn_getlocation() {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            isGPSEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            isNetworkEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnable && !isNetworkEnable) {

            } else {

                if (isNetworkEnable) {
                    location = null;
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {

                            Log.e("latitude", location.getLatitude() + "");
                            Log.e("longitude", location.getLongitude() + "");

                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            fn_update(location);
                        }
                    }

                }


                if (isGPSEnable) {
                    location = null;
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        return;
                    }
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
                    if (locationManager!=null){
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location!=null){
                            Log.e(TAG,"latitude"+location.getLatitude()+""); //Here taking location
                            Log.e(TAG,"longitude"+location.getLongitude()+""); //Here taking location
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            fn_update(location);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        private class TimerTaskToGetLocation extends TimerTask {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        fn_getlocation();
                    }
                });

            }
        }

        private void fn_update(Location location){

            intent.putExtra("latutide",location.getLatitude()+"");
            intent.putExtra("longitude",location.getLongitude()+"");
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }

    }
```